# Request for new Dynamics CRM specific tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Is it possible to create the tag ***dynamics-crm***? There are questions tagged with [crm](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/crm) that are specific to Dynamics CRM.

Maybe it's possible to create version specific tags in addition, like on SO: ***dynamics-crm-4*** and ***dynamics-crm-2011***

See also the tag group on SO: [dynamics-crm*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamics-crm*)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My immediate reaction is that Super User probably isn't the right place for MS Dynamics questions, it's not something the vast majority of computer enthusiasts are ever going to interact with unless they happen to use it at their employer. And any development questions are unsuitable here anyway.

As such, we're not really going to be able to help people get great answers, and the current state of the [crm](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/crm) tag seems to support this theory:

Lets look at the 16 open questions in the tag. 5 of them have no answers at all, and only 3 have an accepted answer. An 18.75% acceptance rate is *very* low (the SU-wide rate is [81%](http://stackexchange.com/sites) at the moment).

Finally, a quick [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/s/1681/tags-with-worst-acceptance-rates) I've just put together on the Data Explorer (which uses non-live data FYI) shows the tag performing quite badly when you take all the tags on the site in to consideration (and I suspect it would perform worse if we ignored single-use tags, for example).

---

A quick search shows there are currently [Enterprise Software](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/22190/enterprise-software) and [Microsoft CRM](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/32455/microsoft-crm) proposals going through definition on Area 51 at the moment (there may be others, as said I just did a very quick search), and much in the same way that SharePoint has ended up with its [own site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/), I suspect these sort of questions would get much better results elsewhere (even if that "elsewhere" doesn't exist yet).

Comment: Thanks for the insights and the analysis. I know that there is not much volume on this site for this topic. IMHO you are correct that Dynamics CRM is probably not the right topic for the audience of superuser. Therefore I'll try to either push the [Microsoft CRM proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/32455/microsoft-crm) or I propose a site regarding the whole Dynamics product line, which should be comparable to the SharePoint site.